# Create a loader with css and js included in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to show a animation when a page is loaded trough ajax with turbolinks.

I created a partial _loader.html.erb and added the code.

The js doesn't seem to fire on ajaxStart or ajaxStop.

I have also tried to wrap the js in $function and $(document) but cant get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    // hide it first
    $(".loading-indicator").hide();
    alert("hide at first")

    // when an ajax request starts, show spinner
    $.ajaxStart(function(){
        $(".loading-indicator").show();
        alert("start")
    });

    // when an ajax request complets, hide spinner
    $.ajaxStop(function(){
        $(".loading-indicator").hide();
        alert("stop")
    });
 </script>

     <%= image_tag("loading.gif", :class => "loading-indicator", :style => "") %>

  <style>
    .loading-indicator {

   }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()` you're just registering handlers that get called when the first ajax request starts and all ajax requests are completed. You never do an ajax request, so they never get called. Use [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to do the actual request.

You could also use the `complete` callback to hide your loading animation:

```
function request() {
    $(".loading-indicator").show();
    $.ajax({
       ...
       complete: function() { $(".loading-indicator").hide(); } 
    });
}
```